# TypeError: $(...).cycle is not a function: jQuery cycle in a JSF application

Tags: jquery, jsf, jquery-cycle

I want to use jquery cycle in one of my pages of a JSF application.
I include jquery form google and I host jquery.cycle.all.js file on my local host and I have another extra js file which contains my jquery cycle slideshow script and I include these files respectively in my page. However the slideshow does not work. Below I include firebug error and my code:

my xhtml page:

```
<h:form>
                                        <div>
                                            <div id="view-slider" class="pics">
                                                <img src="#{request.contextPath}/resources/images/1.jpg" width="400" height="200"/> 
                                                <img src="#{request.contextPath}/resources/images/2.jpg" width="400" height="200"/>  
                                            </div>
                                            <ul id="thumbnails"></ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </h:form>
                                    <br/>
                                    <p:separator/>
                                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" ></script> 
                                    <h:outputScript name="js/jquery-cycle-all.js"/>
                                    <h:outputScript name="js/view-slides.js"/>
```

view-slides.js

```
$.fn.cycle.updateActivePagerLink = function(pager, currSlideIndex) {
    $(pager).find('li').removeClass('activeLI')
        .filter('li:eq('+currSlideIndex+')').addClass('activeLI');
};

$.fn.cycle.updateActivePagerLink = function(pager, currSlide, clsName) {
    $(pager).each(function() {
        console.log(clsName + '; ' + currSlide ); 
        $(this).children().removeClass('activeLI').filter(':eq('+currSlide+')').addClass('activeLI');
    });
};

$(function() {
    $('#view-slider').cycle({
        timeout: 3000,
        pager:  '#thumbnails',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
            return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="50" height="50" /></a></li>';
        }
    });
});
```

Firebug error:

```
TypeError: $(...).cycle is not a function
view-slides.js.xhtml (line 17)
```

So far I have tried the following without success:

wrapped my script inside a function.
checked loading sequence and it is as it should be: jsf.js, jquery, jquery.cycle, view-slides.js
tested this script in a plain html file and it worked.

Extra info:
I have a template which includes the same version jquery.js file from google and has a tabs.js script. These are also loaded and tabs are working. I inserted these too into my html file and it worked fine.
I removied jquery from my xhtml file since I had it in the template and it gave me jquery not found error.

I don't know if it's a conflicting issue or not and if so what does it conflict with?

I appreciate your replies.

Comment: Are you sure that `jquery.cycle.all.js` is loading properly?

Comment: PrimeFaces as being a jQuery based JSF component library already ships with jQuery bundled. Your question suggests that you've manually loaded another one, effectively resulting in two physically different `jquery.js` files being loaded, possibly conflicting each other. Is that true? Why not just relying on PrimeFaces-bundled jQuery? Or were you actually completely missing the whole point of JSF and PrimeFaces?

Comment: Yes Mike W my jquery cycle file is loading. Thank you so much @BalusC I tried this too. But I forgot to remove the script link which I used in my template. I removed it and the problem solved. Please move your comment to answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those kind of `TypeError` errors on jQuery functions are typically caused by having duplicate different versioned jQuery JS files loaded by the webapp. PrimeFaces as being a jQuery-based JSF component library already automatically loads jQuery by itself. You thus do not need to manually load another jQuery JS file yourself on top of PrimeFaces one via `<script>`/`<h:outputScript>`. If you remove it, then this error should disappear.

If you happen to have a page wherein you'd like to use some jQuery, but the page itself doesn't utilize any PrimeFaces component and thus doesn't necessarily have PrimeFaces-bundled jQuery automatically loaded, then you can always explicitly load it yourself by simply adding the following line:

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" />
```

This will explicitly load the PrimeFaces library-bundled jQuery file. Note: the `target="head"` can be omitted when it's already inside the `<h:head>`. Otherwise, e.g. when inside `<h:body>` or `<ui:define>` of a template client, it would be automatically relocated to head. Another note: you can safely use this line in a page which actually requires PrimeFaces-bundled jQuery. It won't end up in a duplciate load.